# Kaggle GPU does not work when tranning a keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu, kaggle

I am training a CNN image recognition model in Kaggle. I am using Keras. I have enabled the GPU accelerator. During the training process **notebook** does not use the GPU. CPU is at 100% usage and GPU is at 0% usage. Do I have to do anything special to get my Keras model to run on GPU, besides enabling GPU in the settings?

I also tried switching to scripting mode and running the same model. No luck :(

I ran the following as suggested in the comments and got these results

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib;print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

Result:-

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 6062022138908879912
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 18244941159629232965
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 15870492672
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 12237251189014729254
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla P100-PCIE-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 6.0"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 13587127940827625526
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```

Model code:-

```
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = train_labels.shape[0] // BATCH_SIZE
base_model = DenseNet121(input_shape=(512, 512, 3),
                                             weights='imagenet',
                                             include_top=False)
base_model.trainable = False 
model = tf.keras.Sequential([base_model,
                             L.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
                             L.Dense(train_labels.shape[1],
                                     activation='softmax')])



model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
model.summary()

history = model.fit(train_dataset,
                    epochs=EPOCHS,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                    validation_data=valid_dataset)
```

Comment: Could you tell me please what is the output of this command `from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib;print(device_lib.list_local_devices())`??

Comment: which version of tensorflow are you using? If it is < 2.0 you need to install tensorflow-gpu python package

Comment: I updated the question with the results obtained from running - from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib;print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

Comment: Tensorflow version is 2.1.0

Comment: Please include the model code, looking at GPU usage is not really a good way to determine if GPU is being used

Comment: Updated with model code

Comment: I used TPU instead of GPU and followed the guidelines provided by [kaggle TPU guide](https://www.kaggle.com/docs/tpu). It worked. CPU Utilization was at 20% and TPU was at 16% max. I managed to train my model within a short duration.